# Using variables with AlertCtrl Ionic

Tags: ionic3

Basically I have an alert control that I wish to display the value of the variable.

```js
let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  message: `
  Are these details correct?  
  <ul>
      <li>Price ($/L):{{dollarPerLitre}}</li>
      <li>KMs Done:</li>
      <li>Total Spent:</li>
      <li>Fuel Type:</li>
      <liDate:</li>
  </ul> 
  `,
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'No',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Disagree clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Yes',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Agree clicked');
      }
    }
  ]
});
confirm.present();
```

{{variable}} doesn't work, but is there anyway I can get it to display the variable contents?

Thanks.

Comment: You should create reference variable in template and use that variable inside component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use proper concatenation while using html inside component class
if `dollarPerLitre` in in current scope use `this` or try to get the value using `ViewChild`.

**Your code is supposed to like:** Observe concatenation carefully.

```js
let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  message: `
  Are these details correct?  
  <ul>
      <li>Price ($/L):`+this.dollarPerLitre+`</li>
      <li>KMs Done:</li>
      <li>Total Spent:</li>
      <li>Fuel Type:</li>
      <liDate:</li>
  </ul> 
  `,
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'No',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Disagree clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Yes',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Agree clicked');
      }
    }
  ]
});
confirm.present();
```